# Regular expression - right pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to ask you how to make a pattern for the following code that finds all the operations that STARTS with the character "Z" and after there is a number and the character "_", for example `Z133.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS`.
The operations might be for example just like this:

```
G_ZLEVEL_PROFILE_0
ZTEST_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z133.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z130.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z127.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z133.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS
Z130.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS
Z127.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS
```

and I need it matchs just operations

```
Z130.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z130.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS
Z127.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z127.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS
Z133.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS
Z133.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS
```

Code:

```
pattern = @"(Z\d*)";

foreach (NXOpen.CAM.Operation operation in operations)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(operation.Name, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
          addToCamOperationGroupList(operationName: operation.Name, folderName: match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you **specifically** want to solve it with a `Regex`?

Comment: @mjwills The answer to that is always `yes` ^_^

Comment: Hi :-) how else could I find all the operations that match all I explained above? :)

Comment: Use: [`(Z\d+\.\d+.+)` and see online at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qrUxYL/1).

Comment: The "easiest" way to solve a regex is to break it into English (or your language of choice).  Is this always the specific pattern: `the string starts with Z, followed by 3 digits, followed by a decimal point, followed by 2 digits, followed by an underscore, followed by other stuff`.  If the pattern is constant, the regex is simple.  If it isn't, it often becomes a whole lot more difficult.

Comment: `Hi :-) how else could I find all the operations that match all I explained above?` There are ways of doing it that don't involve `Regex`. Are they of interest? Or do you **specifically** want to use a `Regex`?

Comment: `Regex` would be much more concise, than just plain C# pattern matching, which would likely also involve multiple iterations over the same string. I see at least 2 `or` statements, using pure C#, which means traversing the same string twice. Performance-wise, pure C# is probably still the fastest way to go, since you have a heck of a lot more options the more lower-level you go. But code-wise, `regex` is super-concise, and self-evident.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
pattern = @"(^Z([\d\.]*_)\S*)";
```

**EDIT:** Updated to match only from the beginning of each line. Test [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eZ%28%5b%5cd%5c.%5d*_%29%5cS*&i=G_ZLEVEL_PROFILE_0%0d%0aZTEST_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aZ133.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aZ130.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aZ127.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aZ133.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aZ130.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aZ127.88_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS%0d%0aSOMETHING_Z123.43_SOMETHING&o=m)

Comment: Note - also matches `SOMETHING_Z123.43_SOMETHING`

Comment: @WonkotheSane updated my answer to cover the case you mentioned also

Answer (score 4):

```
\bZ[0-9\.]+_
```

or

```
\bZ[0-9\.]+_\S*
```

( to get the whole name )

Comment: Note - will also match `SOMETHING_Z123.24_SOMETHING` and `Z123.12.123.12_SOMETHING`

Comment: putting a \b at the start could fix that

Comment: Or you could use ^ for the start of the string

Comment: `\b` matches on `a Z130.88_OP0_WELDAIR_FINISH_WALLS`. Probably want to use `^`.

Comment: Also matches things like `Z........_OP1_COOLING_FINISH_WALLS`. Probably only want to match one period, but op should probably clarify on what exactly a "number" is (float? scientific notation? negative? etc)

Comment: It is hard to know what exactly the OP wants to include / exclude.  If it is a fixed format it would be better to specify three numbers, followed by a decimal, followed by two digits, followed by anything.  At least this gives him a start.

Answer (score 3):

Try below pattern

> `^(Z[\d.]+\_\S*)$`

You can validate it [**here**](http://rubular.com/r/XalhSRsCy9)

Comment: @WonkotheSane Updated the answer